# Multiple PHP Versions on same Apache server

Tags: php, apache

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server with Apache2 hosting 2 sites via virtual hosts. I installed Apache using the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge apache2 
$ sudo apt-get purge php5 libapache2-mod-php5 
$ sudo apt-get purge autoremove 
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Now the server works with PHP 5.5 version. One of my application needs PHP 5.5 and the other needs PHP 5.2. How can I install PHP 5.2 alongside PHP 5.5 and configure the sites to use them accordingly(via `.htaccess` or `vhost-conf`) ? Any detailed answer would be appreciated since I am a newbie to a hosting at this depth.

Comment: Can you supply some code that fails?

Comment: Which code do you need? I just changed the php.ini file and it stopped working. I have attached pic of the error. There is nothing else that seems to help.

Comment: Check the error log for php-errors.

Comment: I checked and it mostly says undefined variables or functions, these are because some included files use short open tags and that is where I have defined them. For further help that you could give me, here is my apache log: http://hastebin.com/ruqobodipo.pas

Comment: You got a huge list of reasonably useful error messages. Read them carefully and eliminate them one by one. If you need help with a particular message, we can help, but we cannot debug your entire script, especially since you didn't post it. Hint: Focus on the Fatals first.

Comment: Ideally, the code that dies (i.e. the code that was running previously, but does not now). The log helps - you have 29 FATAL errors in less than 100 logs. This is obviously a serious concern. Go from there. Fix those, then, come back and let us know how you've gone, post another log, or a better question. Right now, you obviously need to fix the problems that you can fix, before you focus on saying "this worked, then it didn't", because no-one can help you with that sort of issue, without some more information.

Comment: Thanks guys! I really figured out what the problem was. I have now updated the question. Could be great if someone can help with this scenario :)